# Tried installing the Alpaca trading API and I got an error

Tags: installation, python, pip, api

I'm trying to mess around with the [Alpaca trade API](https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-python). 
But when installing I received this error:

> ERROR: requests 2.21.0 has requirement urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1,
>   but you'll have urllib3 1.25 which is incompatible.

Full screen containing error:
[image: error received during install]

Any advice on how to correct it? I've tried updating my `urrlib` but I can't find a version 1.25.1.

Comment: You say you’ve looked for a version 1.25.1, but the message (“requirement urllib3<1.25”) seems to be saying that you need something ***lower**.*

Comment: `python -m pip install --upgrade 'urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1'`